# Where am I going wrong when defining a styleable property for custom textarea

Tags: java, javafx-8

I want to develop a custom textarea in javafx. The first property I want to define is the styleable property missing in the textarea class which is the textFill property so I can programmatically set the color of the text in the textarea. This is important as the textarea is gonna be used in a program where on a click of a button, the color of the text has to be changed.

The problem is that the property value does not affect the text in the textarea. I crossed checked with the javafx api classes and had found that I had followed all the procedure needed to define a styleable property and it's cssMetaData.

Here is the source code of the custom textarea:

```
public class CustomTextArea extends TextArea {

    private ObjectProperty<Paint> textFill;

    public void setTextFill(Paint value){
        textFillProperty().setValue(value);
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Paint> textFillProperty(){
        if(textFill == null){
            textFill = new StyleableObjectProperty<Paint>(Color.BLUE) {
                @Override
                public Object getBean() {
                    return CustomTextArea.this;
                }

                @Override
                public String getName() {
                    return "textFill";
                }

                @Override
                public CssMetaData<? extends Styleable, Paint> getCssMetaData() {
                    return TEXT_FILL;
                }
            };
        }
        return textFill;
    }

    private static final CssMetaData<CustomTextArea, Paint> TEXT_FILL =
            new CssMetaData<CustomTextArea, Paint>("-fx-text-fill", PaintConverter.getInstance(), Color.BLUE) {
                @Override
                public boolean isSettable(CustomTextArea styleable) {
                    return styleable.textFill == null || !styleable.textFill.isBound();
                }

                @Override
                public StyleableProperty<Paint> getStyleableProperty(CustomTextArea styleable) {
                    return (StyleableProperty<Paint>)(WritableValue<Paint>)styleable.textFillProperty();
                }
    };

    private static final List<CssMetaData<? extends Styleable, ?>> STYLEABLES;
    static{
        final List<CssMetaData<? extends Styleable, ?>> styleables =
                new ArrayList<CssMetaData<? extends Styleable, ?>>(Control.getClassCssMetaData());
        Collections.addAll(styleables, TEXT_FILL);
        STYLEABLES = Collections.unmodifiableList(styleables);
    }

    public static List<CssMetaData<? extends Styleable, ?>> getClassCssMetaData(){
        return STYLEABLES;
    }

    @Override
    public List<CssMetaData<? extends Styleable, ?>> getControlCssMetaData(){
        return getClassCssMetaData();
    }
}
```

Here is the main class:

```
public class CustomTextAreaTest extends Application {

    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();

        CustomTextArea area = new CustomTextArea();
        area.setText("Custom text area test");
        area.setLayoutX(10);
        area.setLayoutY(10);

        pane.getChildren().add(area);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Please can you help me identify where I am making a mistake or missing out something. Thanks in advance and please ask for clarification if needed.

Comment: First, you should note that text input controls already define a [`-fx-text-fill` CSS property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#textinputcontrol) that sets the font color, so this seems a bit redundant. But there is nowhere in your code that you actually set the text color when the property changes. (Generally, you would need to do this in the skin.)

Comment: So for example, the current [`TextAreaSkin` implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u60/rt/file/996511a322b7/modules/controls/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/TextAreaSkin.java) has a method `addParagraph()` which is invoked when a new `Text` node is added; it binds the text's `fillProperty()` to the `textFillProperty` (which is actually inherited from `TextInputControlSkin`). So what's missing in your implementation is binding the fill of the text nodes to the value of the property you define.

Comment: Thank you very much. I learned how to inherit TextAreaSkin and implement my custom skin. Now my code is working properly.